# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' to 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase'

Tags: asp.net

I have this method which does not build, it errors with the message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Web.HttpPostedFile`' to '`System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase`'

I really need this to be of type `HttpPostedFileBase` instead of `HttpPostedFile`, I have tried boxing and it does not work:

```
foreach (string inputTagName in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase filebase =HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[inputTagName];
    if (filebase.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        if (filebase.ContentType.Contains("image/"))
        {
         SaveNonAutoExtractedThumbnails(doc, filebase);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A quick peek at Reflector indicates that `HttpPostedFileWrapper` inherits from `HttpPostedFileBase` and accepts an `HttpPostedFile` in the constructor:

```
foreach (string inputTagName in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase filebase = 
      new HttpPostedFileWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[inputTagName]);

    if (filebase.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        //...
```

TheVillageIdiot brings up a great point about the better looping construct, and it will work for you if you're scope exposes the `Request` property of the current HTTP context (e.g. on a `Page`, but not in `Global.asax`):

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase filebase = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(file);
    // ..
```

If you have LINQ available, you could use that as well:

```
var files = Request.Files.Cast<HttpPostedFile>()
                .Select(file => new HttpPostedFileWrapper(file))
                .Where(file => file.ContentLength > 0 
                            && file.ContentType.StartsWith("image/"));

foreach (var file in files)
{
    SaveNonAutoExtractedThumbnails(doc, file);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing you don't need to make it `HttpPostedFileBase` `HttpPostedFile` will work as fine.

Second, `ContentType` is [MIME Content Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), you should look into `FileName`.

Try this code:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        if(file.ContentType.Contains("image/") //as pointed out in comment
        {
            //make second parameter of type HttpPostedFile type
            //where you define method
            SaveNonAutoExtractedThumbnail(doc,file);
        }
    }
}
```